# datepicker as current time

Tags: swift, datepicker, notifications, alert

I am doing an app that will make my datepicker the current time and then it will create an alert. I created the code below so far.but this is giving me an alert immediately after I moved the datepicker:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()


dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(setTime.date)
self.Time.text = strDate

AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1036)

let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "This is an Alert!",  message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: In your code, I understand that you change a value, you emit a sound and you display an alert. What isn't working?

Comment: hi. i want make the datepicker set time as my current time and thats the time that the alert/alarm will send